CGI Script Works Locally but Fails with 404 Error on Server
I'm experiencing an issue with running a CGI script on my Apache web server. The script works perfectly on my local machine, but it fails on the server with a 404 error, indicating that the URL does not exist. Both my local machine and the server are running the same versions of Ubuntu and Apache. The error log on the server reports that Apache is looking for the CGI script in the default location, i.e. /usr/lib/cgi-bin/, and not in the expected location /var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin/. Again, it works fine on my local machine.
[Mon Jun 03 20:17:19.522377 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 78594] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:55973] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.py
In the configuration examples provided, mysite.com is a placeholder for the real URL of the website.
Here are the details of my setup:

Ubuntu Version: 24.04 LTS
Apache Version: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu)
CGI Script Path: /var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin/hello.py
URL: https://mysite.com/cgi-bin/hello.py

Configuration Steps:

Site Configuration:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin/

    <Directory "/var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin">
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


CGI Script (hello.py):
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><body><h1>Test CGI Script for mysite.com</h1></body></html>")


Permissions:
chmod 755 /var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin/hello.py


Enabled Apache Modules:

cgi


Apache Configuration Commands:
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo a2ensite mysite.com.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2



Issue:
When I access https://mysite.com/cgi-bin/hello.py on my server, I receive a 404 error, stating that the URL does not exist. However, the same setup works fine on my local machine.
Observations:
The script works fine from the terminal, i.e.  python3 /var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin/hello.py runs as expected.
Steps Taken to Troubleshoot:

Verified that the CGI script exists at the correct path on the server.
Checked permissions of the CGI script and directory.
Ensured that the CGI module is enabled.
Compared configurations between the local machine and the server.

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working on the server but works locally. Any insights or suggestions on what could be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Do you retrieve an error when trying to open http://mysite.com/cgi-bin/hello.py?

Yes, but I can run the script through php, i.e. I can call the script from php and present the result in the web browser. I suspect that the problem was frigged when I installed Let's encrypt.

Yes, seems to be an issue with the SSL connection / HTTPS.
Are you aware that using CGI for Python is totally old-fashioned and for ~10years the very last option to use? State of technology is ~10 years to use a Python webframework (Flask, Bottle, Django...), server the web application with a Python WSGI server (Gunicorn, Waitress, uwsgi...) and use Apache (or nginx) as a reverse proxy in front of the WSGI server? May sound complicated, but actually it is very easy and way better than CGI.

I need to present a result calculated with Python on a WordPress site, that is PHP, and I'm looking for the simplest way to accomplish this. I can't do much about the site, it is what it is. What would be the best approach to solve this, mixing python with php?

If the CGI approach could solve your problem, the WSGI approach can do it as well.
Except this is this follow-up question not related to Ubuntu at all anymore, you may want to consider raising the follow-up question on PHP / Wordpress / Python e.g. at StackOverflow.

I tried your configs on a freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04 and everything works as expected. So, something you have done on your server is interfering with your ScriptAlias directive.
Try disabling serve-cgi-bin config by doing this:
sudo a2disconf serve-cgi-bin
sudo systemctl restart apache2

